# Using variables as paraments for commands in a bash script

Tags: bash, lubuntu, scripts, password, remote-desktop

I currently have a bash script which I can simply double click to remote desktop into my institution:

```
#!/bin/bash
xfreerdp -f -u myusername -d campus -p mypassword --ignore-certificate website.com
```

Currently I've stored the password as plain text within the script which is most unsecure. Is there a way for the script to ask for user input, store that as a variable, and then pass that variable to the `xfreerdp` command as the password (the bit after the `-p` bit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash


read -p "Please enter your username: " user

read -s -p "Please enter your password: " pass

xfreerdp -f -u "$user" -d campus -p "$pass" --ignore-certificate website.com
```

If you want to do the equivalent with a GUI dialog window, take a look at `zenity` e.g.

```
pass="$(zenity --password)"
```